# Git error "unable to migrate objects to permanent storage" pushing to Azure webapp from bitbucket

Tags: git, azure, bitbucket, azure-web-app-service, kudu

We have a CI workflow that is bitbucket (using pipelines) push to an Azure webapp using their KUDU build service. However, almost every time that runs, we get a git error:

`! [remote rejected] testing -> master (unable to migrate objects to permanent storage)`

If i run the exact same commands from a local copy of git it works fine every time. from Bitbucket, sometimes it works, but very seldomly.

the command we run: `git push https://XXX:XXXX@Webappurl.scm.azurewebsites.net/reponame.git testing:master`
I've also tried adding `-f`

Seems several people have had this problem, [here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/BitBucket-Pipeline-failing-after-Azure-slot-swap/qaq-p/714251), [here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Git-questions/Azure-Web-App-Git-Deploy-Git-Push-not-working/qaq-p/759852), and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a5f6c407-48ab-40d9-a1a1-f689b0068988/azure-web-app-git-deploy-remote-rejected-master-master-shallow-update-not-allowed-?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview). But no answers. Doing a push manually from local git for each CI build is not ideal. Any ideas? My Web app has plenty of storage and not sure how to check any further permission issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this issue by adding clone settings in Bitbucket pipelines. I am not sure why this works but I added it before to resolve this but removed it awhile back. I started getting this issue again, so adding it resolved the problem. But warning is that this may slow down your deployments by a bit as git will do a full clone on the pipelines container. Here is my bitbucket-pipelines.yml config snippet. It just pushes to azure deployment git url. Adding the "clone depth: full" resolves it for me:

```
image: python:2.7.13

clone:
  depth: full

pipelines:

  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          script:
            - git push "https:/...
```

Comment: Yep we did this and it fixed our issues.